# Converting .docx to .pdf in Python (File locked for editing)

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word

Simply trying to convert a .docx to a .pdf

I get hung up on a 'File in Use' notice that I have the file locked for editing when the **doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)** is run. If I copy/paste the original .docx file in the same folder (and adjust the in/out files) and name it anything else, it will convert fine with the code. It just will lock my original file for editing. I would appreciate and input!

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

os. chdir(r'setting current WD')

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = r"C:\Users\first.last\Documents\Folder\File.docx"
out_file = r"C:\Users\first.last\Documents\Folder\File.pdf"

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
print('File Converted!')
```

Comment: So, are you saying if you put the Word doc in the same folder as the script, it works, but if you try to specify a path it doesn't? Also, why are you using `os.chdir()` if you're feeding in absolute paths?

Comment: Basically if I try converting the original file, it gets hung up that the file is in use and can't be edited. If I copy/paste the file though, it will convert it fine. If that makes sense. (Took out the chdir, was in there from a previous iteration)

Comment: If you have the docx open in Word, it will lock the file - close Word. Excel is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine when I run your code no matter the path. Maybe you need to exit ms Word before you try and run it?

Comment: Bingo. It looks like every time the code is run, it leaves an instance running in the background. Is there any way to kill all the active processes when the code is finished using the Word file?

Comment: it seems like you close the object properly. At least in my part it does. There is no issue like the one that you mentioned on my windows 10. One thing I can highlight though, is that sometimes when you close Word it idles in the background, maybe find that process and close it from task manager before you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the necessary changes you want to make and this will execute your specified path.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

def convertFile(file):
    in_file = os.path.abspath(file)
    out_file = os.path.abspath(file.replace(".docx", ".pdf").replace(".doc", ".pdf"))
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()


# minArgsLenght is the value that is used to find out if the user introduced file paths or not, 
# if not, all ".doc" and ".docx" in the current directory are converted.

minArgsLength = 1

if(len(sys.argv)) > minArgsLength:
    for file in sys.argv:
        if file.endswith(".doc") or file.endswith(".docx"):
            convertFile(file)

else:
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".doc") or file.endswith(".docx"):
            convertFile(file)
```

Even if you don't want to add any path in command line just run the file as it is and it will execute on any and every *.doc or *.docx file in the same folder